# Update pandas data frame cell value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Update pandas df cell value to 'negative' if it contains a negative int and 'positive' if it contains a positive int

Initial df

```
ID        Score
apple    -10.5
mango     5.36
banaba   -89.6
carrot    5.3
```

Expected outcome

```
ID       Score
apple    Negative
mango    Positive
banaba   Negative
carrot   Positive
```

I tried for 'negative' update as follows:

`df_up = df[df['Score'] < 0] = 'Negative'`

but got an error

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Did you try that? `df.loc[df.Score < 0, 'Score'] = 'Negative'`

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: You must cast type of `Score` string to integer `df['Score'] = df['Score'].astype(int)`

Comment: I added````df['Score'] = df['Score'].astype(int)```` but got my whole data frame converted to negative string after running ````df.loc[df.Score < 0, 'Score'] = 'Negative'````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convert the `Score` column to numeric type and then do the conversion like this:

```py
>>> df.Score = df.Score.astype(int)
>>> df
       ID  Score
0   apple    -10
1   mango      5
2  banaba    -89
3  carrot      5
```

---

```
>>> df.Score = np.where(df.Score < 0, "Negative", "Positive")
>>> df
       ID     Score
0   apple  Negative
1   mango  Positive
2  banaba  Negative
3  carrot  Positive
```

Comment: Using int type will lead to wrong answer for Scores between 0 and -1, you should use float

Answer (score 1):

If you `Score` is text, you can do:

```
 df['Score'] = np.where(df['Score'].str.startswith('-'), 'Negative', 'Positive')
```

Output:

```
       ID     Score
0   apple  Negative
1   mango  Positive
2  banaba  Negative
3  carrot  Positive
```

Comment: Lol this answer is correct but hilarious. In general I don't think it is a good practice to treat numbers as strings if you can convert them.

Comment: why not? **In this case**, OP is replacing them with `Negative/Positive` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID': ['apple', 'mango', 'banaba', 'carrot'],
                        'Score': [-10.5, 5.36, -89.6, 5.3]})

df['Score'] = np.where(df['Score'] < 0, 'Negative', 'Positive')

df
       ID     Score
0   apple  Negative
1   mango  Positive
2  banaba  Negative
3  carrot  Positive
```

Comment: I imported the data from a CSV file, and its showing error as ````TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'````. I tried by adding ````df['Score'] = df['Score'].astype(int)```` just after importing but it didn't work either.

Comment: I think you should go with astype(float) since you have decimal point numbers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This will set them as well:

```
df['Score']= df['Score'].apply(lambda x: 'Positive' if x > 0 else 'Negative') 

       ID     Score
0   apple  Negative
1   mango  Positive
2  banaba  Negative
3  carrot  Positive
```